# Selecting N points within each geometry using SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, select, grouping

I have grid and point tables in my Postgres db. The points are not equally distributed over the grid. The grid table is 100k+ geometries and the points are in the 100's of millions so efficiency matters some. I want to select N points per grid cell so that I can have an equally distributed sample of points over the grid. I'd also like to, eventually, sample N points per grid cell for distinct device_id's (to avoid having the same GPS device dominate a sample group where it's stationary).

I've had a look at this question on Stackoverflow ["Taking N-samples from each group in PostgreSQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804119/taking-n-samples-from-each-group-in-postgresql) but it seems to focus more on forcing randomness into the data (at computational expense) which I'm not that interested in.

I get that to select 50 points within a specific geom can be achieved with:

```sql
SELECT 
   point_table.id,
   point_table.device_id,
   point_table.geom,
   point_table.some_data
FROM point_table
JOIN grid_table ON ST_Within(point_table.geom, grid_table.geom)
WHERE grid_table.id = 123
LIMIT 50
```

but I'm not sure how to get 50 samples for all grid IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a correlated sub-query for this - a query that essentially does a for-each loop over the running table - and I would suggest a `LATERAL` join for flexibility.

Here we find (up to) 50 pseudo-random points from `points_table` inside the bounding box of each `grids_table.geom` - for *regular (planar, rectangular)* cells, using the `&&` operator is most efficient; use `ST_Intersects` otherwise:

```
SELECT
  grd.id,
  pts.*
FROM
  grid_table AS grd
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      id,
      device_id,
      geom,
      some_data
    FROM
      points_table AS _pts
    WHERE
      grd.geom && _pts.geom
    -- ORDER BY
      -- random()
    LIMIT
      50
  ) AS pts ON TRUE
;
```

**Update:**

I just read that you eventually want unique `device_id` samples; use a rank and fetch query:

```
SELECT
  grd.id,
  pts.*
FROM
  grid_table AS grd
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      id,
      device_id,
      geom
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id,
        device_id,
        geom,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device_id) AS _rank
      FROM
        points_table AS __pts
      WHERE
        grd.geom && __pts.geom
    ) AS _pts
    WHERE
      _rank = 1
    -- ORDER BY
      -- random()
    LIMIT
      50
  ) AS pts ON TRUE
;
```

You can influence ranking with an additional `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause.

*Note that it is mandatory to have a spatial index on `points_table.geom` for this to be efficient!*

Comment: I've always wondered about lateral joins... I'll give it a bash. Thanks

Comment: @RedM here it behaves similar to an inlined, correlated `SELECT *, ( SELECT <correlated_stuff> ... ) AS <alias> FROM <running_table> ...` subquery; it is executed on every row in the running table, having access to the row values. However, unlike inline subqueries, `LATERAL` queries are `FROM` level members, enabling access to (sets of) composite return types (think: a table) rather than just a single value. And it has more to offer.